# Filtering records in oracle DB based on (less than) CURRENT_DATE appears to not be working?

Tags: oracle, sqoop

Have an odd problem where filtering records in an oracle DB using `CURRENT_DATE` (at a certain time) appears not to be working.

I have a daily ETL process that uses sqoop to run the query...

```sql
select a.* from SOURCE_DATA a where 
         POST_DATE > to_date('2020-04-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
         AND POST_DATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) 
         AND \\$CONDITIONS
```

(the lower date is fetched daily based on the highest `post_date` value for records in our local data MSSQL warehouse). I am trying to grab everything beyond that (yet less than the current day's data) from the SOURCE_DATA table in an oracle DB.

This ran on 4/12/2020. Yet, I am seeing that a few records with `post_date` = 4/12/2020 (whereas I would expect only records with, at most, `post_date` = 4/11/2020). Thus, the date filter appears to not be working.

This has happened before when data with `post_date` >= `<current date>` is incrementally added to the source table (which normally only has data from `<current date>` - 1)

---

This sqoop process is run via `airflow` and those sqoop logs show...

```
[2020-04-12 21:32:54,161] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/04/12 21:32:54 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(TDL_ID), MAX(TDL_ID) FROM (select a.* from SOURCE_DATA a where POST_DATE > to_date('2020-04-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd')                 AND POST_DATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) AND  (1 = 1) ) t1
.
.
.
[2020-04-12 21:38:23,086] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 20/04/12 21:38:23 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 1.1264 MB in 331.2884 seconds (3.4816 KB/sec)
```

So we see that th query was run well before 12AM 4/13/2020 (9:32PM - 9:38PM 4/12/2020), the point at which seeing records with `post_date` = 4/12/2020 from the query would make sense.

Checking the timezone on the oracle DB,

```sql
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, SYSDATE, CURRENT_DATE, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE), TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 1) FROM DUAL;
```

we see

```
SESSIONTIMEZONE SYSDATE                CURRENT_DATE            TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)     TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-1)
-10:00          4/13/2020 12:04:28 PM  4/13/2020 12:04:28 PM   4/13/2020 12:00:00 AM   4/12/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

So yesterday's date looks fine and the timezone offset is correct for HST time (which I am in).

Not able to verify the data type of the `post_date` field (the table is actually a view and I have no insight into its construction), but the lower limit of the date filter appears to work fine, so I am assuming its some date type.

Not sure what could be causing this error (not sure if it's a oracle thing or a sqoop thing or something else (hence the multiple tags)). Anyone with more experience have any idea what could be going on here? Further debugging advice?

Comment: Seems `https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/be-aware-of-the-difference-between-currentdate-and-sysdate` may have some input.

Comment: @Slkrasnodar Had seen this earlier, but don't think it is the issue because both the airflow server running the query in the sqoop process and the oracle database server *are in the same time zone* (HST) (which seems to be the issue highlighted in the linked post) (ie. `sysdate` gives me the same result as `CURRENT_DATE`)